# Crear una fila/row con elementos de una lista en flutter

Tags: flutter

estoy intentando crear elementos de una Row() en flutter usando elementos de una lista pero no estoy dando con la solución.

Intenté utilizar List.generate(), pero no me permite utilizarlo en Children:[] de Row().

Con este código, logré hacer bien una Card(), donde creo Inkwells usando información de una lista.

```
children: List.generate(chargers.length, (index) {
                  return Column(children:[
                    InkWell(
                      splashColor: Colors.grey,
                      onTap: ()=> setState(() {
                        if(chargers[index].status == "false"){
                          chargers[index].status = "true";
                        }else{
                          chargers[index].status = "false";
                        }
                      }),
                      child: Stack(
                        children:[ 
                          Icon(Icons.abc_outlined),
                          const Image(image: AssetImage("assets/images/wevecar.png"),
                            height: 80, 
                            width: 80,
                          ),
                        ]
                      ),  
                    ),
                    Center(child: Text(chargers[index].name, style: TextStyle(color: getColor(chargers[index].status)),),)
                  ]);
                })
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: Puedes publicar el código de lo que has intentado? y otra cosa, esta lista será scrolleable?

Comment: No, no sería scrolleable. Ahora comparto el código...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no dejaste el codigo completo , pero deberias hacer algo asi

```
Row(
        children: List.generate(5, (index) => Icon(Icons.car_crash)),
      );
```

o si viene de una lista ya creada podrias hacerlo asi

```
final chargers = ['text','text','text'];
      return Row(
        children: chargers.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es un usar un `for` dentro del `children`, como no publicaste el código del `row` no puedo hacerte un ejemplo igualito, pero sería algo similar, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
Row(children: [
    for(var x = 0; x < chargers.length; x++) //Aquí pones el widget que deseas que se genere si cumple la función
])
```